# How to create double borders through CSS

Tags: css

How to use CSS doing like this? especially double borders (NOT using border:double;)
PS: The HTML code of the Demo: ....1801180218031804 ...

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome on so! the best questions contain snippets of code, but at least they should show what you've tried so we can identify what your problem is. Please also read [this help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I forgot to point out that <div> wouldn't be used. Only <table>, <tr>, <td> in this task are allowed.

Comment: I have tried box-shadow and canvas, those are not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You basically use nesting, meaning the parent container (`.container`) has a border and the child element (.childdiv) has a border. The html (for a single cell) would look like this:

```css
.container,
.childdiv {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
}

.childdiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="childdiv">

  </div>
</div>
```

Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/07v0zm3b/) for a working demo.

Comment: Thanks Gerard for converting it to a stack overflow demo instead of a fiddle, slipped my mind :D

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```css
div {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div:before {
    content: attr(data);
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div data="1898"></div>
```